# List available library - SQL Linked Server AS400

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange

I'm using SQL server 2005 (64bit version) and have successfully connect to as400 using IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries IBMDA400 OLE DB Provider.
Anyone know how to list available library/table and get the field name & description?

already looking around, and have tried this query, but still no luck

```
select * from OpenQuery(AS400, 'select * from QSYS.qadbxatr');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information is available through the catalog views in the **SYSIBM** schema.

Schema (library) information is available in **SQLSCHEMAS**.

Table (file) information is available in **SQLTABLES**.

Column (field) information is available in **SQLCOLUMNS**.

- [V7R1: IBM i catalog tables and views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm)
- [V5R4: ODBC and JDBC catalog views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/db2/rbafzmstcatalogodbc.htm)

Comment: Next to those entries in the Information Center, you will also find ANS / ISO standard views.

Comment: select * from qsys2/systables
select * from qsys2/syscolumns
select * from qsys2/sysindexes